# NTP for TCP/IP(server-client)

Tags: java, client-server, ntp

i have a simple server...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2000);
    Socket sock = server.accept();
    InputStream  in = sock.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(out);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
    ...
```

and a simple client...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",2000);;
    InputStream in= sock.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter w  = new PrintWriter(out);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
    ....
```

-how can i connect more clients to this server? (I need 2 more)
-also i want to send system time from server to clients and then clients will send 
back their time 10 times each plus some fixed delay (0.5-1 sec) then the server must find the average from all delays and send it back to the clients as the new time...

thank you for your time...

Comment: server.accept in a loop and have the sockets returned handeled in a seperate Thread. You might consider using an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` provides the system time

Every Socket returned by `server.accept()` is a separate object and your server can communicate independently with each client through each Socket object. However, since your application is time-sensitive, I would recommend using a separate thread for each client.

A simple server would be:

```
ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(2000);

while (true)
{
    Socket fpSock = serverSock.accept();
    MyThread t = new MyThread(fpSock, this);
    t.start();
}
```

The processing you need will be done in the MyThread run() method. "this" is passed to the thread to provide a reference where each thread can callback to methods in the main class. Make sure to make such methods `synchronized`.

You also don't necessarily need to send the server's time to the client, simply send a generic packet which the client is expected to echo back. Use the server's timestamp for all transactions to avoid variation in client system time.

Comment: Big thx... m8...
It's still hard for me to make coz im not very used to threads and sockets...I'm learning them now...   but I'l give it a try.. :)

Comment: One more question....
Um.... If i have  2 or more infinite loops how can I thread them so they can run together?

Comment: You can have 2 infinite loops with no problem. However, you might want to run only one instance of some methods, and you have to mark them as "synchronized". Read up on Java multithreading and concurrency for more info.